# If N is a sum of two squares, then so is the odd part of N

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, conjectures, sums-of-squares

Given two natural numbers $m,n$, where $m$ is odd. Please prove that if 
$m\cdot2^n$ is a sum of two squares, then $m$ is a sum of two squares. Tested for all $m\cdot2^n<100,000$.

---

I love the natural numbers but feels number theory being inapproachable. So I'm experimenting and mostly (mis)use ME as a "proof calculator". While testing and using my [BigZ](https://github.com/Lehs/ANS-Forth-libraries) I analyze sets and sequences of numbers like below.

```
1 1000 ~ :| n | n sqrsum ; intcond  \ create all square sums in intervall
function odd-part transform-set     \ transform to odd parts
zdup cardinality . 153 
condition sqrsum filter-set         \ only square sums filter
zdup cardinality . 153              \ conclude the conjecture in the question
condition noprime filter-set        \ remove all primes from the set
condition nosqr filter-set          \ remove all squares
set-of-factors                      \ create the set of all prime factor-tuples
cr zet.                             \ and print it:
{(5,197),(3,3,109),(5,193),(13,73),(5,5,37),(3,3,101),(5,181),(17,53),(3,3,97),(5,173),(5,13,13),(7,7,17),(3,3,89),(13,61),(5,157),(3,3,5,17),(5,149),(5,5,29),(17,41),(13,53),(5,137),(3,3,73),(7,7,13),(17,37),(5,11,11),(3,3,5,13),(5,113),(3,3,61),(5,109),(13,41),(5,101),(17,29),(5,97),(13,37),(3,3,53),(5,89),(5,5,17),(3,3,3,3,5),(13,29),(3,3,41),(5,73),(3,3,37),(5,5,13),(5,61),(5,53),(3,3,29),(5,7,7),(13,17),(5,41),(5,37),(3,3,17),(5,29),(5,5,5),(3,3,13),(5,17),(5,13),(3,3,5)} ok
```

From the remaining set the Sum of Two Squares Theorem is almost visible.

Also see [my blog](https://forthmath.blogspot.se/) about using the most low level high level language Forth for mathematical calculations with sets and big integers.

Comment: what has been tried ? what is known that way anyone answering can avoid telling you things you know.

Comment: Hint: an even square cannot be the sum of two odd squares (why?).

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, thanks! ME is my teacher in number theory.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, I tried to stare at the problem for a while, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Lehs you could also look at : http://mersenneforum.org/forumdisplay.php?f=132 first

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$ (a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 = 2(a^2 + b^2) $$

If even $n$ is the sum of two squares, then both are odd or both even; taking $n = c^2 + d^2,$
$$ \frac{n}{2} = \left( \frac{c-d}{2} \right)^2  + \left( \frac{c+d}{2} \right)^2  $$

The rest is induction on the power of 2 dividing you number

Answer (score 3):

The same things apply for any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$

$$  (2a+b)^2 + (a-2b)^2 = 5 (a^2 + b^2)  $$

If $n$ is divisible by $5$ and $n = c^2 + d^2,$ then either both $c,d$ are divisible by $5$ or there is a relation (possibly requiring changing the order and perhaps a $\pm$ sign) of type $d \equiv 2 c \pmod 5.$ Then
$$  \frac{n}{5} = \left( \frac{2c-d}{5}\right)^2 +  \left( \frac{c+2d}{5} \right)^2 $$